# Where should I put a Scanner.close();?

Tags: java

i need to know where i should put a Scanner close in this code to stop resource leak.

```
public class guess_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Random numGenerated = new Random();
         int numToGuess = numGenerated.nextInt(100);
         int numTries =0;
         int Guess;
         boolean win = false;

         Scanner inputNum = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (win == false){

             System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 100");
             Guess = inputNum.nextInt();
             numTries++;

             if (Guess == numToGuess){
                  win = true;
             }
             else if  (Guess < numToGuess) {
                 System.out.println("Your guess is LOW!");
             }

             else if (Guess > numToGuess){
                 System.out.println("Your guess is HIGH!");
             }
         }//End of loop

         System.out.println("You won in " + numTries + " goes. Well done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that, for code, you need to indent everything by four spaces extra, so it all shows up as code. You should also look over your indenting and fix it -- if you're using Eclipse, try selecting everything, then hitting `CTRL+I`.

Comment: okay thanks. im new so thats helpful :)

Comment: I would fix the indenting for you, but for some reason SO isn't letting me edit. It's telling me that your post is mostly code.

Comment: i think you did it, thanks for the help.

Comment: The best answer to this question is to use a "try with resources" block around all the uses of the scanner.  I suggest studying the [online Java tutorial that relates to "try with resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @DavidWallace No, it's not. That's only the "best idea" if you don't know when an exception will be thrown -- and in this case, none will at all. There's no point in wrapping code in a try/catch when it's not going to throw an error.

Comment: @lolcaholic Remember to accept whichever answer worked the best.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I see at least one method call in there that can throw an exception.  So it's really best to use "try with resources".  Just putting a "close" call at the end of the loop is naive.  But even if no such method call existed, it's usually best to code in a "future-proof" way.

Comment: @lolcaholic Don't let the two people who have provided answers pressure you into accepting an answer, until you're ready to.

Comment: @DavidWallace Which method throws an exception? I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: nextInt() @QPaysTaxes

Comment: @DavidWallace Updated my answer. Thanks -- I forgot about how it throws an error if the input isn't an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it after the end of your loop:

```
while (win == false) {
    ...Game logic...
}
inputNum.close();
```

What this does is close the input stream, so you don't have memory leaks.

In addition to that, please follow [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). The only (non-indent related) breaches I saw was that `Guess` is capitalized, but it's an object, and `guess_main` should be `GuessMain` (Uppercase and using camelCase instead of underscores) but it's good to keep an eye out, just in case.

Addendum: As David Wallace pointed out, there is a method that might throw an exception. If you don't care, then the above solution will work, but if you do, this is better:

```
try (Scanner inputNum = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    ...Game logic...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ohh wait i see what i was doing wrong, i think instead of using what i called the scanner to close i was trying to do scanner.close -.-

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Not really. You just said "At the end of the loop", I said "after the end" and gave code to show what I meant.

Comment: @lolcaholic Considering that a lot of people refer to that as `Scanner.close()`, meaning calling `.close()` on a `Scanner` object, the confusion is certainly understandable.

Comment: yeah i see what you mean.

Comment: Comments like "thanks" are depreciated on StackOverflow. You can press the check mark if you wish to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Add it at the end of the loop.**

Things should be closed as soon as you are done using them.
If you do anything else with the scanner afterwords, you will need to move it. For example, if you rewrite it to offer the option for another game, you will need to place the closing statement after your confirm that they don't want to play.

Comment: This isn't the best way to do it. See my comment under the question.

Comment: Granted, it is probably not the best way, but it is the simplest way. I don't think lolcaholic knows enough Java for a try-catch statement.

Comment: That may or may not be true of lolcaholic.  But hopefully, other people will be visiting this page in the future.

Comment: I did a project like this when I was new to programming. And as for the future, I agree.

Comment: I can confirm, I am new to programming.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help.